# How to remove this ancient exhaust fan?

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan, exhaust

It seems to be held in by those metal strips that I can't budge.The wood that it's up against is thin- only about 1/4 inch. And the metal part starts/stops at the visible wood and extends beyond sight into the ceiling. I removed the nails that were in the wood.  [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's going to be hard for us to help you without more info, and in fact the best way is probably tugging on the fan and feeling where it doesn't give (and is likely fastened), which we can't do from here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: You may have to use your phone as a flashlight/remote viewer/enlarger by taking pictures _inside_ the circular opening to see if there are screws that appear to go through the metal and into the joist on the left. You may also have to cut some of the metal, and perhaps, using tin snips, cut hunks of the fan housing out of the way until you find out what it's hung up on.

Comment: Don't be so concern about cutting the drywall to the exact size of the fan.  It is just as easy or easier to patch a larger opening to give you a better view and more working room.  I would cut out at least a couple of inches more at the top and on the right side of the fan.  THis will give you a better idea of how it is fasten.

Answer (score 0):

This is merely a suggestion, but it's possible that each of the 4 clips that I see are attached by nail somewhere up above.

Try cutting each as I've indicated with red lines:

[image]

Then see if you can slip the housing past what *may* be vertical hangars.

Comment: It looks like maybe those can be bent out of the way.   And then bent back for reinstallation  I don't know about old fans, but the new ones (even 30 years old) are designed to make the fan motor easy to replace.